# how to move workspace(a simple project) from windows file system (/mnt/) to linux (~/home)

Tags: linux, windows, wsl-2

I am developing a Django project (nothing) and trying to use using WSL2.

so  if I use the Ubuntu Terminal from Windows to create a project and try running it in VScode, I got this little message,

[image]

I just don't know how to do that at all,

it's the first time I tried to use WSL2 (which is awesome), if someone could help, thank you very much.

Comment: You just do not have the full path set. `/mnt` is the linux filesystem directory under which windows files can be seen from Ubuntu (e.g. `/mnt/c/Users/You`) would provide access to the username `"You"` files on the windows filesystem. To access your Ubuntu files from windows you need `\\wsl\home\You` where `You` is whatever your username is. That may be `\\wsl\Ubuntu-18.04\home\You`., I don't have WSL to check (**note:** this only applies for systems with the May 2019 Update or later, before that you could not edit WSL files from windows without corrupting the Linux file permission bits)

Comment: alright, thank you very much

Comment: You can actually use File Explorer to see that path. Just look under Network. Windows does some magic so WSL now appears as `\\wsl` under Network.

Comment: I could use help with the same issue.
From Terminal app, ubuntu shell, I navigate to a folder and than run "code ." when I get this error.
What should I set where? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still get this message even after cloning my GitHub project to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\<name>\<project>`. My solution after moving/re-cloning the repo from Windows to WSL is to ignore the message. Here are a few observations that might be helpful. (1) The cloned project appeared in a `C:\Users\<name>\<project>` directory. (2) The project does _not_ appear in the `~\home\<project>` with Windows File Explorer. (3) The project _does_ show up from the Terminal app when using `ls` from `~\home`.

Comment: how to actually fix this now ? any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 24):

If you have your project in some mounted folder -> linux path starting with /mnt/ e.g.
`/mnt/c/Users/rasto/Desktop/some_folder/my_project/`

When you open VS Code in this directory (via running command `code .` or opening the VS Code from windows) you get the warning:

*This workspace is on the Windows file system (/mnt/). For best performance, we recommend moving the workspace to the Linux file system (~/home).*

The solution is easy -> move/copy the project folder to `~/my_project/` directory:

**In WSL terminal:**

Recursively copy all files from source-path to destination-path and if the folder *~/my_project/* does not exists, it will be created

```
 cp -R /mnt/c/Users/rasto/Desktop/some_folder/my_project/ ~/my_project
```

Move to the directory in your terminal

```
cd ~/my_project
```

And open VS Code from console with

```
code .
```

**Note:** To open VS Code from terminal you must have installe extension [Remote Development extension pack](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl)

**Note2:** To access the linux folder from windows file explorer just right click in VS Code *explorer* and *Reveal in explorer* or with the path like: **\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\rasto\my_projects**